# Ajax taking too long to come back

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I am recording 2-4 seconds of audio on my website and using Ajax I am posting it to the server. Some time this Ajax take 4-5 seconds, on the other hand some time it takes up to 2 minutes for uploading the same file. The file size is around 360kB. I want the Ajax to drop the file on the server and come back instantly and let the server keep processing it and meanwhile the user can start recording the next file.

I am using webRTC to record audios and working on Yii 1.x

```
//create FormData
        var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append(fileType + '-filename', fileName);
            formData.append(fileType + '-blob', blob);

         callback('Uploading ' + formData + ' recording to server.');
        //ajax call
        makeXMLHttpRequest('captureFile', formData, function(progress) {
            if (progress !== 'upload-ended') {                 
                callback(progress);
                return ;
            }

            var initialURL = '<path to upload a file>';
                 callback('ended', initialURL + fileName);
      });

 function makeXMLHttpRequest(url, data, callback) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                callback('upload-ended');
            }
        };

        request.open('POST', url);
        request.send(data);
    };
```

on success next ajax perform its operation for initiating recording of the next file.

How can I make sure that this ajax only drop the file to the server and return back and server process the file and not stall ajax to finish file processing.

Comment: `360kB` ... which possibly gets encoded in such a way that the sent data is 4/3 times that, which is 480kB ... or 3,840mbits ... on a one megabit upstream connection, that would take over 4 seconds (including overhead) ... so, what is the speed of your internet upstream? This is the deciding factor to how long this takes

Comment: I want Yii to auto trigger audio processing and return the Ajax back to the front end so that user don't have to wait for audio processing to finish. When audio is processed, then maybe we can send an updated about it on the front end.

Comment: yeah ... but what's the upstream speed?

Comment: how can i find that?

Comment: no idea ... speedtest.net - of course, if this code is being used by others, then your upstream speed is irrelevant - it's the end users upstream speed that is impotent

Comment: That's right,  and file size is very small, it shouldn't take so much time to upload a file.

Comment: 360KB on a 1mbit connection will take 4 seconds - now, why do some take 2 minutes? perhaps it's the available upstream capacity, perhaps it's your servers downstream capacity, perhaps it's poor code on your server - not enough information in the question for a definitive answer